# Extract numbers after - in php

Tags: php

I would like to extract the number after "-" in a string but the problem is that I have two "-" I am not sure how to do this in Php

The string looks like this:

> YUH2017-18-510601

I want only 510601 and I want to add 1 to that number.

I tried the following:

```
$ID = "YUH-2017-18-510601";
$ID = substr($ID, -6);
echo $ID;
```

This works fine but what if I have 4 or 5 or 7 digits, this will not work.

I tried even this:

```
$ID = "YUH-2017-18-510601";
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $ID, $matches);
$ID = implode(' ', $matches[0]);
$ID = $ID + 1;
echo $ID;
```

This one gets all numbers and adds one.

But I need the number from the second "-" only?

How to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `strrpos` to find the last occurrence of a `-` in the string, then you can easily calculate how many characters from the end you have to take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ID = "YUH-2017-18-510601";
$ID = explode("-",$ID);
$ID = $ID[3];
echo $ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it'll always return last number number of string

```
$string = "YUH-2017-18-510601";
$string = explode("-",$string);
echo end($string) +1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a string:

```
$id = 'YUH-2017-18-510601';
```

We can [split](http://php.net/explode) it to parts:

```
$parts = \explode('-', $id);
```

And get the [last part](http://php.net/end) incremeneted:

```
$nextNumber = 1 + \end($parts);
```

Nothing fancy:

```
echo $nextNumber;
```